# python recursive function using self.function

Tags: python, recursion

Im quite new to python. and I want to build a little programm for rock paper scissors lizard spok game. But I have a problem calling the fuction within itself with recursion. I always get the error "self not defined". Im not satisfied with my code but i think it will do the job i want it to do. If anyone could give me Feedback I would be very thankful.

```
from random import choice
class rock_paper_scissor_etc:  

    def play(results):
        auswahl = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors","Lizard","Spok"]
        computersChoice = choice(auswahl)
        usersChoice = input()

        if usersChoice == "Rock" :
            if computersChoice == "Rock":
                results.append("draw")
            elif computersChoice == "Paper":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Lizard":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Spok":
                results.append("lose")
            else: 
                results.append("win") #Scissors

        if usersChoice == "Paper" :
            if computersChoice == "Rock":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Paper":
                results.append("draw")
            elif computersChoice == "Lizard":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Spok":
                results.append("win")
            else: 
                results.append("lose") #Scissors

        if usersChoice == "Scissors" :
            if computersChoice == "Rock":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Paper":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Lizard":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Spok":
                results.append("lose")
            else: 
                results.append("draw") #Scissors

        if usersChoice == "Lizard" :
            if computersChoice == "Rock":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Paper":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Lizard":
                results.append("draw")
            elif computersChoice == "Spok":
                results.append("win")
            else: 
                results.append("lose") #Scissors

        if usersChoice == "Spok" :
            if computersChoice == "Rock":
                results.append("win")
            elif computersChoice == "Paper":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Lizard":
                results.append("lose")
            elif computersChoice == "Spok":
                results.append("draw")
            else: 
                results.append("win") #Scissors

        print("User: " + usersChoice)
        print("Computer: " + computersChoice)
        
        print("play again?")
        if input() == "yes":
            print("test")
            self.play(results)
        else:
            print(results)
            
    results = []   
    play(results)
```

Comment: Hello, Christian. `self` should be the first argument of the method `def play(self, results)`. It's not implicitly defined in Python as is in some other languages.

Comment: Add `self` to the `play` method's argument list?

Comment: Of course, when you do that, the next problem will probably be a complaint about not passing enough arguments when calling the function, because you're calling `rock_paper_scissor_etc.play(foo)`, and not `rock_paper_scissor_etc().play(foo)`. A class really has no use in this case here…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.play(results)` will not work, because there is no `self` defined. `self` is commonly used as the name of the first parameter of a method, but you have not included that parameter. Nor have you made the *initial* call of `play` as a method call.

While you could fix that, there are some reasons why you should not pursue this programming pattern:

- The recursion will become deeper and deeper for each player move. It makes more sense to create a loop, and exit that loop when the user does not want to play anymore.
- The class is not really useful:

  - You don't create an instance of it
  - If you would, it would not carry any state

  So create a plain function without a class

Other remarks / suggestions:

- Instead of requiring that the caller of `play` must provide an empty list, let the function *return* the list.
- When you ask for input, provide a prompt as argument to `input`
- The logic for determining the winner can be made a bit shorter:

  - First check if both players had the same guess. Then you know it is a draw
  - Then use the `in` operator to check whether there was a win
  - Test for all winning combinations in one expression (using `or`)
- You should check that the user has chosen a valid option and repeat asking for input until that is the case
- Maybe allow that the user enters a choice in a different capitalisation (all upper case or all lower case,...). So turn all input to lowercase, and also initialise the possible options with all-lowercase letters.

Here is code that takes the above into account:

```
from random import choice

def play():
    results = []
    auswahl = ["rock","paper","scissors","lizard","spok"]

    while True:
        computersChoice = choice(auswahl)
        usersChoice = input("Choose " + ", ".join(auswahl) + ": ").lower()
        while usersChoice not in auswahl:
            usersChoice = input("Not a valid choice. Choose " + ", ".join(auswahl) + ": ").lower()

        if usersChoice == computersChoice:
            results.append("draw")
        elif (usersChoice == "rock" and computersChoice in ("lizard", "scissors")
               or usersChoice == "paper" and computersChoice in ("rock", "spok")
               or usersChoice == "scissors" and computersChoice in ("paper", "lizard")
               or usersChoice == "lizard" and computersChoice in ("paper", "spok")
               or usersChoice == "spok" and computersChoice in ("rock", "scissors")):
            results.append("win")
        else:
            results.append("lose")

        print("User: " + usersChoice)
        print("Computer: " + computersChoice)
        
        if input("play again (yes, no)? ") != "yes":
            print(results)
            return results
        
results = play()
```

Comment: Thank you for the working Code, i really appreciate! And i also really appreciate the Comments! Things make more sense now :)